# Programmatic add / remove services at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core

As far as I have been able to do is to add new services though the IServiceCollection

Is there a way to add and remove these services at run time?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();

AzureMultiTenantServiceBuilders.Build(services);
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to configure additional AzureAd for our tenants at run time without having to restart the system.

```
public static class AzureMultiTenantServiceBuilders
{

    public static void Build(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        foreach (var tenant in Tenant.GetAll())
        {
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddAzureADTenanted(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = tenant.ClientId;
                    options.TenantId = tenant.TenantId;
                    options.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
                });
        }
```

I found this [Installing a new middleware at runtime in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56751443/1841839) which was close as its adding middleware but what i am trying to do is adding a service at runtime so this isnt helping.

```
public static class RuntimeMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddRuntimeMiddleware(this IServiceCollection services, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
    {
         services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(RuntimeMiddlewareService), typeof(RuntimeMiddlewareService), lifetime));

        AzureMultiTenantServiceBuilders.Build(services);
        return services;
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRuntimeMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IApplicationBuilder> defaultAction = null)
    {
        var service = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<RuntimeMiddlewareService>();
        service.Use(app);
        if (defaultAction != null)
        {
            service.Configure(defaultAction);
        }
        return app;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a better approach would be to have custom middleware which performs the authentication stuff, and **that** middleware can validate against its own internal cache/database which can be updated at runtime.. I don't think it's possible to add/amend things once the serviceprovider has been built.

Comment: I am not sure i cant set up a custom middleware in Identity server to handle that its already doing it.  But i will start digging.

Comment: Are you just trying to add a scoped/transient/singleton service to your collection?

Comment: I am trying to add new AddAzureADTenanted as we get new tenants.  They are external login providers

Comment: Are you aware of these tenants? Can they be added to an appsettings json file? Or are you calling some API and retrieving them at runtime?

Comment: It will need to be called by an api run time they will be stored in the database but we are going to have to tell the server to load them when a new one pops in

Comment: I think you're looking to inject new services into the iservicecollection container outside of the composition root but you can't. It would be great if you could pass in the iservicecollection into a piece of middleware and add the service! This may be a work around for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174474/injecting-service-in-middleware-in-asp-net-core